# Calculate covariance matrix from observations

Tags: normal-distribution, matlab, covariance

I am trying to calculate covariance matrix from a 2D data, assumed from coming from a Gaussian Distribution. I am trying to calculate using the equality that $\mathrm{Var}[x] = \mathrm{E}[x^2] - \mathrm{E}[x]^2$, so supposing that `D` is the data matrix where rows are observations, the MATLAB code is:

```
[mean(D(:,1).^2) - mean(D(:,1))^2 , mean(D(:,1).*D(:,2)) - mean(D(:,1))*mean(D(:,2)) 
 mean(D(:,1).*D(:,2)) - mean(D(:,1))*mean(D(:,2)) , mean(D(:,2).^2) - mean(D(:,2))^2]
```

However `cov(D)` gives me an entirely different covariance matrix. Of course I can use `cov()` and go on my life but I am using the calculation method above in another different piece of C++ code, so it is nice to learn where I am doing wrong.

I think I am missing a crucial and fundamental information here but could not figure it out. Any help?

Comment: Exactly *how* does your formula differ from `cov(D)`? For instance, is there a constant ratio of the components of `cov(D)` to the components of your calculation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For ease of presentation, let us restrict to two random variables, say $X_1$ and $X_2$.
[The covariance matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix) is given by
$$\Sigma = \left( \begin{array}{cc} \textrm{Var}(X_1) & \textrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2) \\
                           \textrm{Cov}(X_2, X_1) & \textrm{Var}(X_2) \end{array}\right).$$
Since $\textrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2) = \textrm{Cov}(X_2, X_1)$, only three entries have to be estimated.

Say you have one sample from each of $X_1$ and $X_2$ available to you:
$$\{x_{11}, \ldots, x_{1n}\} \qquad \textrm{and} \qquad \{x_{21}, \ldots, x_{2n}\}.$$
The natural empirical estimates are given by
$$\widehat{\textrm{Var}(X_k)} =\widehat{\textrm{Cov}(X_k, X_k)} = \frac{1}{n-1} \sum_{i = 1}^{n} (x_{ki} - \bar{x}_k)^2; \qquad k = 1, 2$$
$$\widehat{\textrm{Cov}(X_1, X_2)} = \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum_{i=1}^n (x_{1i} - \bar{x}_1) (x_{2i} - \bar{x}_2)$$
with $$\bar{x}_k = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ki}; \qquad k = 1, 2.$$

Comment: Although this is correct, what is the answer to the question? What is the "crucial and fundamental information" that the OP may be overlooking?  (I suspect, as I hinted in a comment, that it may be as simple as the use of $1/(n-1)$ instead of $1/n$.)

Answer (score 4):

I believe @whuber's comment nailed it. Here is a simple way to debug your Matlab code:

```
n = 1024;
D = randn(n,2);
C = [mean(D(:,1).^2) - mean(D(:,1))^2 , mean(D(:,1).*D(:,2)) - mean(D(:,1))*mean(D(:,2)) ; ...
mean(D(:,1).*D(:,2)) - mean(D(:,1))*mean(D(:,2)) , mean(D(:,2).^2) - mean(D(:,2))^2];  % OP code
C2 = cov(D);
disp(C ./ C2);   % they have the same value! i.e., C = k C2 for scalar k.
disp(n * C - ((n-1) * C2));  % zero + roundoff error.
```